# What is the difference between scale invariance and scale free?

Tags: terminology, scale-invariance, scales

A [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65751/) several years ago asked, "What is the difference between scale invariance and self-similarity.   It appears that a new term has become popular in recent years, which is "scale free".  What is the difference between scale free and scale invariant?

Comment: I think this question needs a bit more work to clarify what you want to know.

Comment: Is it better now?